# In JSON how to achieve a recursive addition of same key value pairs to one of the existing key using C#

Tags: c#, json, recursion, data-structures

I've been trying different to accomplish this,
my input is:

```
string statment = "(Entity.CIFNumber <> '3123' AND Entity.Country LIKE 'USA' AND (Entity.FYEMonth= 'May' OR Statement.ProgitBeforeTax= '123123' OR STATEMENT.NetSales <= 234234 OR STATEMENT.statementdatekey_ = '2019/07/01'))";
```

I want to convert it to JSON:

```
 "DataSetCommonQuery": {
      "operator": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "ENTITY.CIFNumber",
          "condition": "<>",
          "value": "3123"
        },
        {
          "field": "ENTITY.Country",
          "condition": "LIKE",
          "value": "USA"
        },
        {
          "operator": "OR",
          "rules": [
            {
              "field": "ENTITY.FYEMonth",
              "condition": "=",
              "value": "May"
            },
            {
              "field": "STATEMENT.ProfitBeforeTax",
              "condition": ">=",
              "value": 123123
            },
            {
              "field": "STATEMENT.NetSales",
              "condition": "<=",
              "value": 234234
            },
            {
              "field": "STATEMENT.statementdatekey_",
              "condition": "=",
              "value": "2019-07-01 12:00:00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

What I've done so far: 
These are my classes:

```
public class DataSetCommonQuery
    {
        public string @operator { get; set; }
        public List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>(); 
    }
    public class Rule2
    {
        public string field { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rule
    {
        public string field { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string @operator { get; set; }
        public List<Rule2> rules = new List<Rule2>(); //{ get; set; }
    }
```

I tried recursion but not able to access or add the new operator, rules object to the existing rules array. I might be missing something very obvious but been stuck with this for three days..

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Base
{

}

public class Operation : Base
{
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public List<Base> rules { get; set; }
}

public class Rule : Base
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
}

Operation op = new Operation
{
    @operator = "AND",
    rules = new List<Base>
    {
        new Rule { field = "ENTITY.CIFNumber", condition = "<>", value = "3123" },
        new Rule { field = "ENTITY.Country", condition = "LIKE", value = "USA" },
        new Operation { @operator = "OR", rules = new List<Base>
                                                    {
                                                        new Rule { field = "ENTITY.FYEMonth", condition = "=", value = "May" },
                                                        new Rule { field = "STATEMENT.ProfitBeforeTax", condition = ">=", value = 123123 },
                                                        new Rule { field = "STATEMENT.NetSales", condition = "<=", value = 234234 },
                                                        new Rule { field = "STATEMENT.statementdatekey_", condition = "=", value = new DateTime(2019, 7, 1, 12, 0, 0) }
                                                    }
                      }
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(op, Formatting.Indented);
```

The generated json

```
{
  "operator": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "ENTITY.CIFNumber",
      "condition": "<>",
      "value": "3123"
    },
    {
      "field": "ENTITY.Country",
      "condition": "LIKE",
      "value": "USA"
    },
    {
      "operator": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "field": "ENTITY.FYEMonth",
          "condition": "=",
          "value": "May"
        },
        {
          "field": "STATEMENT.ProfitBeforeTax",
          "condition": ">=",
          "value": 123123
        },
        {
          "field": "STATEMENT.NetSales",
          "condition": "<=",
          "value": 234234
        },
        {
          "field": "STATEMENT.statementdatekey_",
          "condition": "=",
          "value": "2019-07-01T12:00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint. I created the classes as you suggested. While I come across the sub query I and recursively calling the same function and the function adds the new set of field, condition,value under the existing rules array itself. Again the same issue I was facing.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the problem then, can you clarify what you mean _While I come across the sub query I and recursively calling the same function and the function adds the new set of field, condition,value under the existing rules array itself_?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, When my code comes across the field ENTITY.FYEMonth (which is in subquery referring to input in my question). ENTITY.FYEMonth is getting appended to the existing key rules[]. You see in the answer you responded ENTITY.FYEMonth is in rules[{rules[ENTITY.FYEMonth]}] which is right. For me the FYEMonth is still under the first level rules list. like rules[ENTITY.CIFNumber, ENTITY.Country, *ENTITY.FYEMonth*]

Comment: My question is more like how do I use the base class recursively. I know I making some mistake there. I guess